# Understanding the Sensors Applet

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel, applet, temperature

I just installed the package `sensors-applet` and I'm having a hard time reading the outputs. It's giving me 4 different temperature readings:
[image]

The first two (*TZ01* and *temp1*) always give exactly the same reading (usually 50°C/122°F); however, *TZ01* properties says that 60°C is a high value, while *temp1* properties says that 90°C is a high value. **I'm assuming they're both the CPU, but which one has the correct high value?**

Furthermore, I still don't know what the other two are about. They always report similar (but not identical) temperature levels (usually around 15-17°C/58-64°F). **What are they?**

I'm running a single core laptop (Athlon Neo)with inboard graphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thermal sensor are specific to a each computer type. For example, the IBM/Lenovo Thinkpad series sensors are described here http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Thermal_sensors

Try to search the Internet for you laptop type and see where each sensor is positioned.

Answer (score -2):

Gnome sensors applet works fine (for my Asus K52F, Ubuntu 10.10). Please, install the latest version of sensors applet from here [link text](http://sensors-applet.sourceforge.net/index.php?content=packages). During installation process do not forget to mark hdd daemon startup loading.
I personally choose the following sensors: Libsensors Temp1, hddtemp.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work. I'm asking what the names mean.